# Warning: findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-dom, deprecation-warning, strict-mode

I get this error when i click on select dropdown field while trying to edit.
It says : **findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode. findDOMNode was passed an instance of Transition which is inside StrictMode. Instead, add a ref directly to the element you want to reference.**

[image]

Here is the link to the codesandbox,

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-material-ui-0yqeo?file=/src/components/exercises/Form.js

Comment: [Issue is known and getting addressed in Material-UI Version 5 release.](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/183f267fa5995ea2c6c2abd4517164204e74382e/docs/src/pages/guides/migration-v4/migration-v4.md#non-ref-forwarding-class-components)